# procedural solution to iterate through nested object

Tags: javascript

I want to get all children of type 'FIELD' (o1_child1, ... o2_child2) from object below and I want to keep the function procedural (I have seen functional style solutions I can't understand so I don't want to use unless syntax is understandable for me). But my attempt below doesn't work, do you see a fix ?

```
  let object = {
    o1: {
      type: 'CONTAINER',
      children: {
        child1: {
          type: 'FIELD'
        },
        child2: {
          type: 'FIELD'
        }
        
      }
    },
    o2: {
      type: 'CONTAINER',
      children: {
        child1: {
          type: 'FIELD'
        },
        child2: {
          type: 'FIELD'
        }
        
      }
    }
  }

  let fields = [];

  function godeeper (parent) {
      let fields = [];
      for (const child of parent.children) {
          
          if (child.type === "FIELD") {
              fields.push(child);
          } else {
              fields.push(iterate(child));
          }
      }
      return fields;
  }
  for (const child of object.children) {
      if (child.type === "FIELD") {
          fields.push(child);
      } else {
          fields.push(godeeper(child));
      }
      
  } 
  alert(fields.length);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it can help you.

```js
let object = {
    o1: {
        type: 'CONTAINER',
        children: {
        child1: {
            type: 'FIELD'
        },
        child2: {
            type: 'FIELD'
        }
        
        }
    },
    o2: {
        type: 'CONTAINER',
        children: {
        child1: {
            type: 'FIELD'
        },
        child2: {
            type: 'FIELD'
        }
        
        }
    }
}

let fields = [];

function godeeper (parent) {
    let fields = [];
   
    for (const [key,child] of Object.entries(parent.children)) {
        
        if (child.type=="FIELD") {
            fields.push(child);
        } else {
            fields.push(godeeper(child));
        }
    
    }
    return fields;
}
for (let [key, parent] of Object.entries(object)) {
    for (const [key,child] of Object.entries(parent.children)) {
       
        if (child.type=="FIELD") {
            fields.push(child);
        } else {
            fields.push(godeeper(child));
        }
        
    } 
}

console.log(fields.length)
```